# Strip HTML tags with Content Javascript

Tags: javascript

I Tried many things like :

```
var StrippedString = OriginalString.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"");
var StrippedString = OriginalString.replace(/<(?:.|\n)*?>/gm, '');

Input : Hello there i am an input string<p> with html content </p>.
Output : Hello there i am an input string with html content .
```

But it will only strip html tags leaving contents of the tags. What i want is remove any html code from string.

```
Input : Hello there i am an input string<p> with html content </p>.

Expected Output : Hello there i am an input string.
```

Comment: That's not so easy to do. You can check some ideas here ; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be on the right path. But you are only checking for the first closing tag. Try checking for two closing tags with this regex:

```
 <[^>]+>[^>]+>
```

This will match:

*Hello there i am an input string`<p> with html content </p>`.*

With your js it will look like:

```
var StrippedString = OriginalString.replace(/<[^>]+>[^>]+>/g,"");
```

<sub>I don't think you need to ignore the case in this situation as you aren't specifying any case for any character</sub>

---

### Edit:

As user torazaburo pointed out, that expression will not work for nested tags. If you want a regular expression that will be able to work with nested tags, you need to begin using matching groups:

```
<([A-z]+).+\/\1>
```

The parenthesis are "matching group 1" and whatever is matched within the parenthesis is repeated when we recall the matching group with `\1`.

This will match:

*Lorem `<span class="s1">ipsum <a href="http://stackoverflow.com">dolor sit amet</a>, consectetur adipiscing elit</span>`. Nulla et imperdiet nisl, et scelerisque augue.*

It will also correctly match:

*Lorem `<span class="foo">ipsum <span class="bar">dolor sit amet</span>, consectetur adipiscing elit</span>`. Nulla et imperdiet nisl, et scelerisque augue.*

Because the regex is looking for the last occurrence of the closing tag. Not simply the first one.

Comment: I'm deeply unconvinced this will work for nested tags.

Comment: @torazaburo You are very correct. This will not work in any way shape or form for nested tags. I have updated my answer in order to better support nested tags. However, It still won't work if there are any child tags that are the same type as the parent. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: @torazaburo Nevermind. I figured out a way to get all html as long as the html is written correctly (and doesn't include self ending tags) See my edit for the change.

Comment: I suppose you want to allow spaces between the left angle bracket and the tagname. I'm not sure `[A-z]` works, shouldn't it be `[A-Za-z]` and maybe include some other characters such as dash for custom elements, colon for namespaced elements, etc.?